# Issue while downloading easyadmin bundle on PHP/symfony5

Tags: php, symfony, symfony5

I am currently facing an issue **while downloading the easyadmin bundle on my Symfony5 project** in order to add an admin interface. The error is not coming from the yaml files  as (this bundle is not using yaml in his 3.0 version but I already tried with minor versions).
I got a KO when the script cache:clear.Then the installation fails.

`In FileLoader.php line 173:`

`There is no extension able to load the configuration for "paths" (in "/Users/guilhem/workspace/symfony_project/config/packages/twig.yaml"). Looked for namespace "paths", found ""framework", "twig", "twig_extra", "sensio_framework_extra", "doctrine", "doctrine_migrations", "security", "web_profiler","monolog", "debug", "maker", "knp_paginator", "stof_doctrine_extensions","easy_admin"" in /Users/guilhem/workspace/symfony_project/config/packages/twig.yaml (which is being imported from "/Users/guilhem/workspace/symfony_project/src/Kernel.php").`

`In YamlFileLoader.php line 773:`

`There is no extension able to load the configuration for "paths" (in "/Users/guilhem/workspace/symfony_project/config/packages/twig.yaml"). Looked for namespace "paths", found ""framework", "twig", "twig_extra", "sensio_framework_extra", "doctrine", "doctrine_migrations", "security", "web_profiler","monolog", "debug", "maker", "knp_paginator", "stof_doctrine_extensions", "easy_admin"".`

`Script @auto-scripts was called via post-update-cmd`

`Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original  content.`

**My PHP version is 7.4.3**

Am I missing something ? Does anyone already faced this issue ? Thanks guys.

**I already tried the following commands :**

`composer.phar require stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle`
`composer.phar require antishov/doctrine-extensions-bundle`
`composer.phar require admin`
`composer.phar require easycorp/easyadmin-bundle`

Comment: Avoid using images in questions.  Just paste in the relevant portions of the error.

Comment: Ok sorry I am new in this and not english native so I'll improve in this lol

Comment: Have you tried running `composer install`? This error usually occurs when you are missing dependencies and configs cant be parsed.

Comment: @CodeSpirit I already installed it but for no reason it runs composer.phar instead of composer

Comment: Its the same, you can just config it to run under composer. Another solution would be to remove (copy somewhere else) the config files which are throwing errors. Install your packages, then install packages relevant for the error causing configs and merge your config into the created config files.

Comment: @CodeSpirit thanks for your response, actually the problem was an incorrect line added on the twig.yaml, by just deleting it and updating composer.phar to composer now everything works.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, the answer was within the error msg.

There is no extension able to load the configuration for 'paths' (in '/Users/guilhem/workspace/symfony_project/config/packages/twig.yaml').

So you know there a typo on the twig.yaml config file.

Comment: thanks for your response, actually the problem was an incorrect line added on the twig.yaml, by just deleting it and updating composer.phar to composer now everything works.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem was an incorrect line added on the twig.yaml, by just deleting it and updating composer.phar to composer now everything works.